# How can I convert a value of a variable to StringVar or IntVar() to .get() it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get the value in a variable to place it to a text file. But I don't know what method should I do. I tried to convert it using the statement `self.score = StringVar()` or `self.score = str(self.score)` or `self.score = IntVar()`. But it results to what I am not expecting. I need help to fix this for my project. These piece of my codes may help you understand. Thank you.

```
        self.score = IntVar ()
        f = open('E.txt','a')
        f.write(self.name_ent.get() + '-' + self.score.get() + '\n')
        f.close()
```

`self.score.get` was error, because it's an `int`.

Comment: Please cut your code down the minimal necessary to show the problem.

Comment: f.write(self.name_ent.get() + '-' + self.score.get() + '\n')                    f.close()

Comment: @needhelp no, it isn't - there's still too much code and too little explanation. What happens when you `.get()` the values, what exactly is the problem? I'm guessing you're struggling with adding an integer to a string - why not use `str.format`, or explicitly convert the value from `self.score.get()`?

Comment: It's really unclear. Please edit your question to add more information about what you want to get.

Comment: this is all the specific information i can give . its okay if u cant understand .

Comment: Have you tried `str(self.score.get())`?

Comment: Good luck for your deadline, have a nice coding night.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an instance of `IntVar`, the `.get()` method returns an integer -- that's why you would use `IntVar` vs. `StringVar`. Like any other integer in python, you convert it with [str](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-str):

```
score = str(self.score.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error from trying to concatenate an integer with a string when forming the string to write to the file.  This is the basis of your error.  You can fix it by making the 'int' into a 'str' with a simple cast, `str(some_int)`.  In your case, changing `self.score.get()` to `str(self.score.get())` on line 3 will do the trick.

Alternatively, you could make self.score a StringVar() instead of an IntVar() on line 1, and then the problem on line 3 goes away. You still need to assign a value to the score, which you can do with `self.score.set(value)`.

By default, an IntVar() gets the value 0 and a StringVar() get the value of "" (the empty string).  You can assign a value to an IntVar in at least two ways:

(1) on creation, with `iv = IntVar(value=1)`

and

(2) after creation, with `iv.set(1)`

The same goes for StringVar(), as well.

Changing self.score to a StringVar() from an IntVar() may seem a little strange at first, but just be aware of the difference in the default values.